# Facebook login on my own website

Tags: facebook, authentication

I'm trying to use facebook to login to my website. Everything is working well apart from the face I have to click the login button twice. The first time seems to log me into facebook and the second time seems to call the fb.login function. Below is my code. Can I do the whole process in just one click?

```
----- LOGIN BUTTON ----
<a class="btn-auth btn-facebook" href="##" onclick="checkLoginState();" >
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i>
    <span>Sign in with Facebook</span>
</a>

----  JAVASCRIPT ----
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
 function statusChangeCallback(response) {
console.log('statusChangeCallback');
console.log(response);
// The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
// app know the current login status of the person.
// Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
// for FB.getLoginStatus().
if (response.status === 'connected') {
  // Logged into your app and Facebook.
  testAPI();
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
  FB.login();
} else {
  // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
  // they are logged into this app or not.
  FB.login();
}
}

 // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
 // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
 // code below.
 function checkLoginState() {
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
});
  }

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.1'
});

};

function logoutUser() {
  FB.logout(function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
  return false;
}

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
// successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  var fbName = response.name;
  if(response.location){
    var location = response.location.name;
  }else{
    var location = '';
  }
  var fbLoginPrefix = 'fb_';
  var params = "Name="+response.name+"&Id="+response.id+"&Email="+response.email+"&Location="+location+"&LoginPrefix="+fbLoginPrefix;
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/iCareWallet/services/login.cfm",
       data: params,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(resp)
       {
         if(resp == 0){
            window.location = "/my-profile"    
        }else{
            window.location = "/join-icw/params/display/editprofile"  
        }

       },
       error: function (json, status, e)
       {
        alert("There was a problem login in. Please try again");        
       }
   });
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
})
, {scope:'email'};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must call `FB.login` directly on user interaction (mouse click), or Browsers will most likely block it. Right now you are calling the asynchronous (!) function `FB.getLoginStatus` before trying to call `FB.login`. Make sure you understand the concept of asynchronous callbacks in JavaScripts, that´s pretty important to know.

`FB.getLoginStatus` should be used right after `FB.init` and only once per page load.

I suggest reading this article for more information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/